# Why does RedirectToAction redirects to <param>.com

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

We have a mvc4 site where the HomeController.Index() has the following code

```
RedirectionToAction("Page", new { id = "Home" } );
```

where action Page is defined as

```
 public ActionResult Page(string id)
    .....
```

on debug, it starts as `localhost:xxxxx` but then redirects to `www.home.com`

on setting the breakpoint, it does not even hit the method `Page(string id )`

Any clues on where to look ?

Comment: Do a solution-wide search for `home.com` You probably have it defined somewhere and it's causing the redirect (maybe your default error-page?)

Comment: @Kenneth already did and didn't find it

Comment: Do you get a redirect through JavaScript or a 301 / 302?

Comment: What is there in your Routeconfig.cs file?

Comment: @Kenneth  how do i find that out ?

Comment: @guanxi the defaults, nothing changed there

Comment: Use a tool like HttpFiddler to detect what you get when you request `localhost:xxxx`

Comment: Did you change the Default Route?

Comment: You need to look at your routing configuration for MVC. It's not understanding how to map /Page/Home to a controller.

Comment: Check the routes configuration in `Global.asax.cs`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may have some routing issues.  The RouteConfig.cs file is in the App_Start folder in your MVC4 project.

One other thing, if your Page action is in a different controller than your HomeController, then you need the code to be like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return RedirectToAction("OtherController", "Page", new { id = "Home" });
}
```

I created a basic MVC4 project with the redirection you have and it works for me.  User ends up at the following URL:  [http://localhost:47272/Home/Page/Home]

Here's my HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   //
   // GET: /Home/

   public ActionResult Index()
   {
      return RedirectToAction("Page", new { id = "Home" });
   }

   public ActionResult Page(string id)
   {
      return View();
   }
}
```

Here's my RouteConfig.cs

```
public class RouteConfig
{
   public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
   {
      routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

      routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Default",
          url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
      );
   }
}
```